# Why always $\frac{V}{I}$ is constant?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, conductors

The integral of the electric field along a conductor carrying a current $I$ equals
the voltage difference $V$ between the endpoints of the integral :
$$V=\int_a^b \vec{E}(\vec{r}) \  \ d(\vec{r})$$
If the material of the conductor satisfies Ohm's law, then the voltage difference will be
given by :
$$V=\int_a^b  \rho(\vec{r})\vec{j}(\vec{r}) \  \ d(\vec{r}) \tag{1}$$
Now the ratio of $V$ given by  (1) to $I$ given by $I=\int \vec{j}(\vec{r}) \ \ d\vec{A}$  will be a **constant** ; We define this **constant** quantity $R$ that's mean:
$$V=IR$$

that :

$$R:=\frac{\int \rho (\vec{r})\vec{j}(\vec{r}) \ \ d\vec{r}}{\int \vec{j}(\vec{r}) \ \ d\vec{A}}$$

---

my question :

Why always $\frac{V}{I}$ is **constant** ?

Comment: Because that is Ohm's law. Which the material was assumed to satisfy.

Comment: What Pieter said: your question states that it is a given that the material satisfies Ohm's Law. If a material satisfies Ohm's law — which by the way far from all materials/components do; diodes for instance do not satisfy Ohm's Law — then it is given from the outset that V over I is constant.

Comment: Only if $\sigma$ doesn't depend on the electric field.

Comment: @Pieter How can i  from $\vec{j}=\sigma \vec{E}$ Concluded  $\frac{V}{I}=\text{constant}$

Comment: The current is the integral of $\vec{j}$ over the cross sectional area, the voltage is the integral of $\vec{E}$ over the length.

Comment: ... which is what you stated. The mathematical proof is easy in the case of a straight wire.

Comment: You should correct equation (1) and the last equation and replace $\sigma$ by $\rho$! Alternatively, you can divide $j$ by $\sigma$  in both cases.

Answer (score 4):

The symbol $\sigma $ usually designates the conductivity of a material. Thus your equation (1) is wrong. The factor of $j$ in equation (1) should be the resistivity $$\rho = \frac {1}{\sigma}$$

The resistance is only a constant when the conductivity of the material is constant and doesn't depend on the the electric field strength. This means that the $I/V$ characteristic (or $j/E$ characteristic) is linear. Many conductors, especially semiconductors, have nonlinear characteristics like a saturation of the current at high voltages. This is due to so-called hot-electron effects.

Comment: So if we have $\vec{j}=\sigma \vec{E}$ then The resistance is  a constant , if $\vec{j}=\sigma (\vec{E}) \vec{E}$  then   The resistance is Not constant . is it right ?

Comment: @Almot1960 You completely right! When the conductivity (or equivalently, resistivity) depends on the electric field strength, then your resistance will not be constant. It will depend on the applied voltage.

Comment: thaks a lot .Now ow to prove that : if $\vec{j}=\sigma \vec{E}$ then The resistance is a constant

Comment: @Almot1960 Your last equation proves it. If the integrals in the numerator and denominator are constant, then your resistance $R$ is constant.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the expression $$R = \frac{V}{I}$$ only *defines* the resistance, it does not mean that the resistance is a constant, *i.e.* independent of the applied potential difference. When $R$ *is* a constant then it means that if you change the applied potential difference, $V$, you can *predict* the current, $I$.

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP asked why V over I is assumed to be constant *in the case specified by the question*. This answer says it is not constant, which is true in the general case but not in the specific case of the question.